# Auto increment dynamic textbox div ID and result show in incremented div ID from another jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I use below script for dynamic textbox.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
     var counter = 0;
    $(function () {
    $("#btnAdd").bind("click", function () {
        var div = $("<div />");

        div.html(GetDynamicTextBox(""));
        $("#TextBoxContainer").append(div);
    });
});

function GetDynamicTextBox() {

    return 'Item Code : <select name="iuname" id="iuname" class="required">' + <? php foreach($tItem as $row): ?>
        '<option value="<?php echo $row->ProductID;?>"><?php echo $row->ProductID;?></option>' + <? php endforeach; ?>
        '</select>' +
        ' Batch : <input id="buname" name="buname" >' +
        '<div id="ffinalResult' + counter + '" ></div>' +
        '<br/>'
    counter++;
}
</script>
```

When I'll change Item Code from drop down it will show result in ID= `ffinalresult`. It show result perfectly for first textbox. But when I change next drop down it show result in same div= `ffinalresult`.But I want to show result in different div ID for different drop down value. I use counter but its not working.

```
<script>
    $(document).on('change', '#iuname', function() {
        var val = $(this).val();
        var text = $(this).find('option:selected').text();
        $("#ffinalResult").text(val);
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Move `var counter = 1;` to global scope

Comment: I already move but its not working @Satpal

Comment: can you write your html codes,too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you increase counter after return, It wont be increased.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var counter = 0;
    $(function () {
    $("#btnAdd").bind("click", function () {
        var div = $("<div />");

        div.html(GetDynamicTextBox(""));
        $("#TextBoxContainer").append(div);
    });
});

function GetDynamicTextBox() {
   counter++;
    return 'Item Code : <select name="iuname" id="iuname" class="required">' + <? php foreach($tItem as $row): ?>
        '<option value="<?php echo $row->ProductID;?>"><?php echo $row->ProductID;?></option>' + <? php endforeach; ?>
        '</select>' +
        ' Batch : <input id="buname" name="buname" >' +
        '<div class="ffinalResult" rel="' + counter + '" ></div>' +
        '<br/>'

}
</script>
```

Comment: Auto increment working on dynamic textbox. But how I will increment result div ID.  $("#ffinalResult").text(val); @kamuran Sonecek

Comment: use rel attribute and class instead of ID .  $(".ffinalResult[rel='"+ ID + "']").text(val)

Comment: I use this instead of ID. '<div class="ffinalResult' + counter + '" ></div>'+             <script>
 $(document).on('change', '#iuname', function(){
  counter++;
    var val = $(this).val();
    var text = $(this).find('option:selected').text();
     $(".ffinalResult[rel='"+ counter + "']").text(val)
    
 });
 </script>   But its not working. @Kamuran Sonecek

Comment: separate ID and class name. Set ID as attribute value in rel

Comment: I use this also '<div class="ffinalResult' + counter + '" id="ffinalResult" >Masud</div>'+  but not working @Kamuran Sonecek

Comment: <script>
    $(document).on('change', '#iuname', function() {
        var val = $(this).val();
        var text = $(this).find('option:selected').text();
        $("#ffinalResult").text(val);
    });
</script>   Here, how can I replace #iuname by $(".iuname[rel='"+ counter + "']")      help me @Kamuran Sonecek